# Do I need to do anything specific for a Primary ToolbarItem to appear disabled on Android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="tbiEdit" Text="Edit" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Command="{Binding ToggleEditCommand}">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="Android" Value="ic_edit_white_24dp.png"/>
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Icons/ic_edit_dark_48dp.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="tbiSave" Text="Save" Order="Primary" Priority="2" Command="{Binding SaveOrderCommand}">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="Android" Value="ic_save_white_24dp.png"/>
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Icons/ic_save_dark_48dp.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="tbiCopy" Text="Copy" Order="Secondary" Priority="3" Command="{Binding CopyOrderCommand}">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="Android" Value="ic_content_copy_white_24dp.png"/>
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Icons/ic_content_copy_dark_48dp.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="tbiDelete" Text="Delete" Order="Secondary" Priority="4" Command="{Binding DeleteOrderCommand}">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="Android" Value="ic_delete_white_24dp.png"/>
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Icons/ic_delete_dark_48dp.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

When testing on UWP, the Primary `ToolbarItem` objects, Edit and Save, correctly appear disabled out when the bound command object's `canExecute` returns `false`, and when it returns `true`, appears as enabled. This is the same for the two  two secondary `ToolbarItem` objects, Delete and Copy, in the secondary menu.

When I deployed to my Samsung Note8 to test, Edit and Save always appear enabled. Copy and Delete appear as expected in the secondary menu. Edit and Save do not actually execute the action though, its just the appearance.
I am not familiar with Android at all, and am relying heavily on Xamarin.Forms in this respect, so am wondering if there is something that I need to do specifically on the Android side of things to have the enabled/disabled appearance according to the bound command's `canExecute` function?

EDIT (Add code):
As requested, Command code for save and edit.

```
private bool CanSave()
    {
        if (!IsVMInEditMode) return false;
        if (!DisplaySaveWarning) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title)) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Details)) return false;
        if (Title.Length > 50) return false;
        if (Details.Length > 1000) return false;
        return true;
    }

private bool CanToggleEdit()
    {
        if (_order == null) return false;
        if (!_order.IsUserCreated) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your command code?

Comment: @Billy, have updated the post with the check logic. I hope this is the code you were after.

Comment: @Lindsay I was wondering if you are still having this issue?

Comment: @MatthewRegul, sadly, yes I am.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. I would suggest filing an issue on the Xamarin.Forms repo: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues   
Do make sure you try with the latest Xamarin.Forms release to make sure it is not something that was already addressed.

Comment: Lindsay I'm not able to reproduce the problem you describe. When my Command returns false for canExecute, it's appearance and behavior is disabled on UWP and Android. I'm using Xamarin.Forms 3.1 and Android AppCompat. As @jgoldberger suggested, if you are still not getting the result you expect, please file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks @DavidOrtinau. Project is currently on Forms 3.0, but was on an earlier version when I asked this. Upgrading to 3.1 is on the agenda. Regarding AppCompat, I haven't specifically done anything around that as I hoped for as much out of the box as possible. Is this something needed to get it working? For what its worth, the phone is running Android 8.0.0. min target on the project is 5.0, and compile target is 8.1